# Fat model skinny controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm, design-patterns

I'm trying to refactor a controller with the following logic.
:

```
    def recover_password
      if params[:login].present?
        if User.exists?(id: params[:login])
          render plain: "Recover by id" status: :ok
        elsif Utils.is_email?(params[:login])
           render plain: "Recover by email" status: :ok
        else
           render plain: "Email not found" status: :unauthorized
        end
      else
        render plain: "Login not found" status: :unauthorized
      end
    end
```

I tried to send business logic to the `User` model, but I do not know if it's a good alternative:

```
def recover_password
  result = User.recover_password(params)
  render plain: result status: :status
end
```

What is the best alternative to refactor this code? Send to Model and return the messages? But how to return the message and the status code?

P.S: I can't create another method / action in the controller to separate the ways to recover the password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it is a good idea to add this logic to the User model. You can move it to the controller private method.

```
def recover_password
  result = check_params(params[:login])
  render plain: result[:message], status: result[:status]
end

private 

def check_params(login)
  return { message: "Login not found", status: :unauthorized } if login.blank?
  return { message: "Recover by id", status: :ok } if User.exists?(id: login)
  return { message: "Recover by email", status: :ok} if Utils.is_email?(login)
  { message: "Email not found", status: :unauthorized }
end
```